# How not to show specific value in for loop?

Tags: python

I am listing all file names into a list in Python.

here is my current code:

```
import os
from os.path import isfile, join

test = 'C:/Users/Nelly/Desktop/test folder'

one = [f for f in os.listdir(test) if isfile(join(test, f))]

print(one)
```

This code above, returns me a list of all file names. I have a specific value I do not wish to return, which is `Thumbs.db`. Not sure what it is, but it shouldn't be in the list.

How do I exclude it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an additional condition to your comprehension:

```
one = [f for f in os.listdir(test) if isfile(join(test, f)) and not f == 'Thumbs.db']
```

or if you want to just filter on the extension:

```
one = [f for f in os.listdir(test) if isfile(join(test, f)) and not f.endswith('.db')]
```

Comment: thank you.. do you know what `thumbs.db` is showing up?

Comment: `Thumbs.db` is a file like any other, so `os.listdir` will list it normally. As far as what it is, [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/330788/495437) states that they're for storing file thumbnails and they're only visible if you have "Show hidden files/folders" enabled in Windows.